# How to get the required key value from JMeter JSON Response

Tags: json, jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I want to validate my API response which is in JSON format. In my case I want to get and validate 'IsActive' value for 'SysCreatedUserId' or for particular 'Id'. Please find the below JSON file. I tried with JSON Assertion but no success till now. Can anyone please help on the same.

```
[
  {
    "Version": null,
    "StatusCode": 200,
    "Result": [
      {
        "AccountId": "e26290ff-38c9-4733-a3d3-e57d5f8318ef",
        "OrganizationLevelTypeId": "b2761fb7-cb1e-4860-81c4-7205e7b742d7",
        "Name": "LevelName_-928016457_updated",
        "ParentId": null,
        "IsActive": true,
        "RowVersion": "",
        "IsWolfpack": false,
        "LastActivityDate": "2018-06-21T09:38:50.83",
        "WolfpackConfiguration": {
          "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "LevelId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "AssociationLevelId": null,
          "IsPublic": false,
          "Level": null,
          "AssociationLevel": null
        },
        "ChildOrganizationLevels": null,
        "OrganizationLevelUsers": [],
        "FragmentSettings": null,
        "OrganizationLevelCode": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "SysCreatedUserId": "720abe00-1267-4ede-aa0f-505e11f806de",
        "SysEditedUserId": "720abe00-1267-4ede-aa0f-505e11f806de",
        "SysCreatedDateTime": "2018-06-21T09:38:50.83",
        "SysEditedDateTime": "2018-06-21T09:38:51.82",
        "Id": "3cb5ee8d-1382-49fc-850c-013c65ab81b0"
      },
      {
        "AccountId": "e26290ff-38c9-4733-a3d3-e57d5f8318ef",
        "OrganizationLevelTypeId": "b2761fb7-cb1e-4860-81c4-7205e7b742d7",
        "Name": "LevelName_-1910968947_updated",
        "ParentId": null,
        "IsActive": false,
        "RowVersion": "",
        "IsWolfpack": false,
        "LastActivityDate": "2018-06-21T10:26:38.28",
        "WolfpackConfiguration": {
          "Id": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "LevelId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
          "AssociationLevelId": null,
          "IsPublic": false,
          "Level": null,
          "AssociationLevel": null
        },
        "ChildOrganizationLevels": null,
        "OrganizationLevelUsers": [],
        "FragmentSettings": null,
        "OrganizationLevelCode": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
        "SysCreatedUserId": "720abe00-1267-4ede-aa0f-505e11f806de",
        "SysEditedUserId": "720abe00-1267-4ede-aa0f-505e11f806de",
        "SysCreatedDateTime": "2018-06-21T10:26:38.28",
        "SysEditedDateTime": "2018-06-21T10:26:39.74",
        "Id": "30ebcf1c-35a2-4135-91d0-0b2b08564361"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Filter Expression](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#operators) like:

```
$..[?(@.Id == '3cb5ee8d-1382-49fc-850c-013c65ab81b0')].SysCreatedUserId
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSON PAth Extractor]

More information: [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)